# Haskell search an element on a List

Tags: haskell

I want a function that changes (1 to 0) on a list of lists, when number of 1's in that line/column isn't even. I have done these functions:

1) Sees if the lines in a list are even or not:

```
  parityLine :: [[Int]] -> [Bool]
  parityLine [] =[]
  parityLine (x:xs)
                |sum(x) `mod` 2 == 0 = True:(parityLine(xs))
                |otherwise = False:(parityLine(xs))
```

2) Sum the corresponding elements on a list of lists:

```
 sumPositions :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
 sumPositions [] = []
 sumPositions (x:xs) = foldl (zipWith (+)) (repeat 0) (x:xs)
```

3) Sees if the columns in a list are even or not:

```
 parityColumn :: [Int] -> [Bool]
 parityColumn [] = []
 parityColumn (x:xs)
    |head(x:xs) `mod` 2 == 0 = True:parityColumn(xs)
    |otherwise = False:parityColumn(xs)
```

4) Does the operation or with two boolean lists:

```
 bol :: [Bool] -> [Bool] -> [[Bool]]
 bol  [] _ = []
 bol (x:xs) (y:ys)= (map (||x) (y:ys)):(bol xs (y:ys))
```

5) Correct List:

```
 correct :: [[Int]] -> [[Bool]]
 correct [] = []
 correct (x:xs)=(bol(parityLine (x:xs))(parityColumn(sumPositions(x:xs))))
```

So what I want is to alter the function `correct` to [[Int]]->[[Int]] that does this:

```
    My Int list(x:xs)                 With my correct function applied

    [[0,0,1,1],                            [[True,True,True,True],
     [1,0,1,1],                             [True,True,False,True],
     [0,1,0,1],                             [True,True,True,True]
     [1,1,1,1]]                             [True,True,True,True]]
```

Now I can see that in the second line third column, False, so I have to correct that number 1 to have a number of 1's even. If there is more than one False in that list, I only want to correct one of these 1's.

As a result, I want that function `correct` returns:

```
 [[0,0,1,1],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [0,1,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the overall result you want to achieve? Your description just states, that you want to change one (arbitrary?) 1 into 0 if the number of 1s is not even, but your code suggests a more specific goal. Do you want to modify the input such that all lines and columns have an even number of ones?

Comment: Also, do you have some kind of minimality requirement, i.e. do you want to turn as few 1s as possible into 0s? Because, right now, your correct function will happily turn a cross of ones (`[[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]`) into all `False`.

Comment: I just want to change the number [[Int]] at the same position where matrix [[Bool]] is False. I just want to change one of them in case of list [[Bool]] has more than one False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give an answer that starts where you are rather than from scratch, so we're doing it more your way than mine.

First let's do it for a single element:

```
leaveIf :: Bool -> Int -> Int
leaveIf yes 0 = if yes then 0 else 1
leaveIf yes 1 = if yes then 1 else 0
```

(You could use guards for that, but my phone doesn't have the vertical bar character!)

Next we can do it for a list of lists:

```
edit :: [[Bool]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
edit boolss intss = zipWith (zipWith leaveIf) boolss intss
```

---

EDIT: You'd like to only change one, so we'll need a way of making subsequent `False`s into `True`s:

```
makeTrue :: [Bool] -> [Bool]
makeTrue xs = map (const True) xs
```

I've used the function `const :: a -> b -> a`. For example, `const 5 'c'` is just `5`. I could shorten that definition to `makeTrue = map (const True)`. Once you get used to thinking that way, you'll find the shorter version clearer.

```
oneFalse :: [[Bool]] -> [[Bool]]
oneFalse [] = []
oneFalse (xs:xss) = let (trues,falses) = break (==False) xs in
     case falses of 
       [] -> trues:oneFalse xss
       (False:others) -> (trues ++ False : makeTrue others) : map makeTrue xss
```

`(==False)` could be written more simply as `not`, but less clearly perhaps.
so for example

```
> oneFalse [[True,True,True,True],[True,False,True,False],[True,False,False,True]]
[[True,True,True,True],[True,False,True,True],[True,True,True,True]]
```

So now we can have

```
editOne :: [[Bool]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
editOne boolss intss = zipWith (zipWith leaveIf) (oneFalse boolss) intss
```

Comment: I have made a mistake the second line and third column has the wrong number, not the first line.

Comment: The solution still seems to be correct. `leaveIf` can also be written als `leaveIf yes x = if yes then x else 1 - x` to make the toggling nature more clear.

Comment: Your solution corrects all numbers and I just want to correct one of them, sorry for I don' t have mentioned it, how can I do this? Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1887556 It only corrects the ones where you have a False.

Comment: @AndrewC The description later changed to only change one of the False

Comment: @user1887556 Fixed to only do one.

Answer (score 2):

AndrewC already gave an solution which changed *all* `1`s corresponding to `False`s. If we only want to correct the first one, we have to find a replacement for `zipWith`:

```
leaveIf ok x = if ok then x else 1 -x

-- Varianto of zipWith, which changes at most one element of the list
modFirst :: Eq b => (a -> b -> b) -> [a] -> [b] -> [b]
modFirst _ [] _ = []
modFirst _ _ [] = []
modFirst f (x:xs) (y:ys) = z : if y == z then modFirst f xs ys else ys
  where z = f x y

edit :: [[Bool]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
edit boolss intss = modFirst (modFirst leaveIf) boolss intss

correct' :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
correct' xss = edit (correct' xss) xss
```

The result is the not necessarily a list of lists where all lines/rows contain an even number of 1's:

```
correct' [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]] = [[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]
```

You need to iterate it a few times, until all errors are fixed (i.e., compute a fixpoint).

---

I'd like to add that your original program can be simplified quite a bit (without changing your algorithm):

```
parityLine :: [[Int]] -> [Bool]
parityLine = map (even . sum)

parityColumn :: [Int] -> [Bool]
parityColumn = map even

sumPositions :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
sumPositions = foldl (zipWith (+)) (repeat 0)

bol :: [Bool] -> [Bool] -> [[Bool]]
bol xs ys = map (\x -> map (||x) ys) xs

correct :: [[Int]] -> [[Bool]]
correct xs = bol (parityLine xs) (parityColumn $ sumPositions xs)
```